# Best UX for loading several files and rename them

Tags: drag-n-drop, upload, file-input

I have this screen where the user uploads up to 10 files, each one of them needs to be renamed to describe what's its content (fixed descriptions), I already rename the files as they are loaded, but is really tedious to open the file explorer 10 times. I thought a drag and drop would work better since you can split your windows and start moving files from folder to navigator, so 2 questions:

1. Is there a better way than drag and drop each file?
2. Is there a drag&dorp that lets you assign a name for each file loaded? (would be a list)

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard upload operation with extra information requested on completion.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the context of any operation, which is repeatable - it is worth automating.

It's possible to implement a mechanism that will generate files from the given name:

- "Title [id]"
- "Title [d + 1]
- "Title [id + 2] (...)

If instead, name should be different - maybe to introduce some repetitive interface that facilitates the identification of files.

**Process could look like this:**

- file identification
- name entry
- enter

**Drag and drop** can work on the entire information collection/list (if : "CTRL + right click") (probably not in every software)